# visual studio 2012 new windows store app on windows 8 firewall error

Tags: windows-8, visual-studio-2012, compiler-errors, app-store, windows-store-apps

im install VS2012 on windows8 with SDK

from menu File >> New Project >> XAML app project

and after get developer license, when i want to compile it, this error accured

[image: Registration of the app failed]

> Error 1   Error : DEP0700 : Registration of the app failed. error
>   0x80073D0A: Failed to install package
>   8eec1bd4-3f98-43a7-ab51-d73e1a3612a0_1.0.0.0_neutral__bcxhannxafppp
>   because the firewall service is not running. Ensure that the firewall
>   service is enabled and started. (0x80073d0a)  App1

i have another third party firewall that disabled windows firewall automatically .

after googling find some [article like this](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w8itpronetworking/thread/c9a5bcbe-da7b-4962-bb5c-5fb376051be1/) about

> Hi, Please try the following:
>
> 1. Disable or remove the WinpkFilter to see how it works.
> 2. Use System Restore to get back to the previous state which it worked.
> 3. Regarding the error message, please also check: Error Message: Not enough storage is available to complete this operation. 
>      http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc978736.aspx Thanks.

did you recommend i desable the firewall or restore the system?

when i go to Control Panel\System and Security\Windows Firewall\Customize Settings

[image: enable the firewall]

can i uninstall last updates instead of system restore?

isnt there another way recommend for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@jan-hommes said : disabling the third party firewall should be an option to try.

- I uninstall my enterprise antivirus (that it dont allow me to turn my firewall on)
- then go to services and after change its setting to start automatically

my problem solved.

so i try to Google many times and use this [article](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-security/windows-firewall-cant-change-some-of-your-settings/2679690e-c375-4232-ae45-404374386635): this **article usefull when i uninstall my firewall.**

> 1. Click on Start
> 2. In the start Search box type Services
> 3. Right Click on - RUN AS ADMIN Check if the below mentioned services has the mentioned status and start up type.
>
> windows firewall      Started      Automatic\Manual. base filtering
>   engine      Started      Automatic\Manual. windows firewall
>   autorization driver      Started      Automatic\Manual. Also check the
>   dependency services that are required for Windows Firewall Service to
>   run. To check that double click on the service and click on the
>   dependency tab.

Answer (score 2):

I facing similar problems some times and didn't find a right way around. Here are some conclusion what might help:

- this error often occurs if you re-deploy an app with the same package
  ID from visual studio if it is already installed by a different user
  -> Solution- change the Package Identity (open the manifest, go to the package tab and modify the identity).
- Clean and rebuild your application by right clicking on the solution
- delete the `bin` folder in your solution copy the project to a new solution and rebuild it
- restart your system

don't know why, but often the error disappears after I have done one of the things above. I found this mostly in mdsn forums.

Also disabling the third party firewall should be an option to try.